# NVIDIA Surround and 2 touchscreens on Windows 10

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, touchscreen, nvidia

I have 2 touchscreen monitors horizontal layout, connected via DisplayPort and USB to the same computer.

Need to use bezel compensation, so would need to use NVIDIA surround to do so.
After NVIDIA Surround enabled, 2 monitors convert into 1 virtual monitor, 7480x2160 px.

However, there is no way that I can use both touchscreens at the same time to control two different 'monitor portions' nor the chance to map the surface of the monitor (that corresponds to the 50% of the image, left or right) that I want to control with each touch surface.

I tried DisplayFusion but I still can't use Windows tablet calibration as for Windows there is only 1 monitor and not 2.

Any ideas?